# Force Distinct Records from Multiple Field Criteria Inner Joins

Tags: sql

I'm trying to return a distinct list of patients given certain criteria.  I'm using an inner join to look at all patient records that meet a certain criteria and then look at the MAX service date, and further the MAX charge amount for that day, to force a unique record.  Below is an abbreviated example showing that a patient may have had 4 charges on the same service date.

[image]

I want to pull the MAX charge on THAT day to get a distinct record match.  However, my current code is concatenating the MAX service date with a MAX charge from ANY found service date, creating a hypothetical record such as the following from the above example:

```
10/3/2016   9/30/2016   Sebert, Stephen L MD  76598   CHG   238
```

This record does not exist in the database so I'm losing the count and not returning a match to get the patient demographic information.  I hope this makes sense.  Here's my code.  I'm using an inner joing to do it.  Please let me know if there is a better way.  Do I need to do a second nested inner join to accomplish this?

```
SELECT  PAT.V51_PRSNPERSONNUMBER AS PSNNMBR,
(PAT.V51_PRSNFIRSTNAME + ' ' + PAT.V51_PRSNLASTNAME) AS NAME,
ADDR.V8_PERSONHOMEADDRLINE1 AS ADDRESS,
ADDR.V8_PERSONHOMEADDRLINE2 AS ADDRESS2,
ADDR.V8_PERSONHOMEADDRCITY AS CITY,
ADDR.V8_PERSONHOMEADDRSTATE AS STATE,
ADDR.V8_PERSONHOMEADDRZIP AS ZIP,
ADDR.V8_PERSONHOMEPHONENUMBER AS PHONE,
ADDR.V8_PERSONMOBILEPHONENUMBER AS CELLPHONE,
PAT.V51_PRSNEMAIL AS EMAIL,
'LOCASCIO REQUEST' AS GROUPS
FROM I_DNCHGSPMTS CP
LEFT OUTER JOIN IPROCEDURE PR
    ON (CP.DNCP_PROCEDURECODE = PR.PRPROCEDURECODE AND CP.OFFICE_ID = PR.OFFICE_ID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VSTAFFCHGBILL STFBILL
    ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = STFBILL.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_PRACTICEID = STFBILL.V69_STPRACTICEID AND
        CP.DNCP_STAFFID_CREDITED = STFBILL.V69_STSTAFFID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VPROVCHGBILL BILL
    ON (STFBILL.V69_STSTAFFID = BILL.V58_PROVPROVIDERID AND STFBILL.OFFICE_ID = BILL.OFFICE_ID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN I_DNCHGCOVERAGE CHGCV
    ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = CHGCV.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_CHARGESID = CHGCV.TPSCHARGESID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VDNPLANCHGCV1 CV
    ON (CHGCV.CHGCVR1PLANID = CV.V9_DNPLANID AND CHGCV.OFFICE_ID = CV.OFFICE_ID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VDEPTCHG DEP
    ON (CP.DNCP_DEPARTMENTCODE = DEP.V4_DPTDEPARTMENTCODE AND CP.OFFICE_ID = DEP.OFFICE_ID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VDNADDRSPAT ADDR
    ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = ADDR.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_PATIENTID = ADDR.V8_TPSPERSONID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VPERSONPAT PAT
    ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = PAT.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_PATIENTID = PAT.V51_PRSNPERSONID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN IACCOUNT ACC
    ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = ACC.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_ACCOUNTSID = ACC.ACCACCOUNTSID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN IPAYMENT PMT
    ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = PMT.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_PAYMENTSID = PMT.PMTPAYMENTSID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VLUPROCCLASS CL
    ON (PR.OFFICE_ID = CL.OFFICE_ID AND PR.PRCLASS = CL.V85_LUCLOOKUPCODE)
LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VSVCCNTRPROC SVC
    ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = SVC.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_SERVICECENTERID = SVC.V75_SVCSERVICECENTERID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN I_DNDXPROCEVENT DX
    ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = DX.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_PROCEDUREEVENTSID = DX.TPSPROCEDUREEVENTSID)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  CP.DNCP_PATIENTID AS PSNNMBR,
        MAX(CP.DNCP_FROMSERVICEDATE) AS SVCDT,
        MAX(CP.DNCP_AMOUNT_CHARGE) AS CHGAMT
    FROM I_DNCHGSPMTS CP
        LEFT OUTER JOIN IPROCEDURE PR
            ON (CP.DNCP_PROCEDURECODE = PR.PRPROCEDURECODE AND CP.OFFICE_ID = PR.OFFICE_ID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VSTAFFCHGBILL STFBILL
            ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = STFBILL.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_PRACTICEID = STFBILL.V69_STPRACTICEID AND
            CP.DNCP_STAFFID_CREDITED = STFBILL.V69_STSTAFFID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VPROVCHGBILL BILL
            ON (STFBILL.V69_STSTAFFID = BILL.V58_PROVPROVIDERID AND STFBILL.OFFICE_ID = BILL.OFFICE_ID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN I_DNCHGCOVERAGE CHGCV
            ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = CHGCV.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_CHARGESID = CHGCV.TPSCHARGESID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VDNPLANCHGCV1 CV
            ON (CHGCV.CHGCVR1PLANID = CV.V9_DNPLANID AND CHGCV.OFFICE_ID = CV.OFFICE_ID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VDEPTCHG DEP
            ON (CP.DNCP_DEPARTMENTCODE = DEP.V4_DPTDEPARTMENTCODE AND CP.OFFICE_ID = DEP.OFFICE_ID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VDNADDRSPAT ADDR
            ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = ADDR.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_PATIENTID = ADDR.V8_TPSPERSONID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VPERSONPAT PAT
            ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = PAT.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_PATIENTID = PAT.V51_PRSNPERSONID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN IACCOUNT ACC
            ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = ACC.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_ACCOUNTSID = ACC.ACCACCOUNTSID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN IPAYMENT PMT
            ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = PMT.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_PAYMENTSID = PMT.PMTPAYMENTSID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VLUPROCCLASS CL
            ON (PR.OFFICE_ID = CL.OFFICE_ID AND PR.PRCLASS = CL.V85_LUCLOOKUPCODE)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN I_VSVCCNTRPROC SVC
            ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = SVC.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_SERVICECENTERID = SVC.V75_SVCSERVICECENTERID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN I_DNDXPROCEVENT DX
            ON (CP.OFFICE_ID = DX.OFFICE_ID AND CP.DNCP_PROCEDUREEVENTSID = DX.TPSPROCEDUREEVENTSID)
    WHERE CP.OFFICE_ID = 'EDQV'
        AND CP.DNCP_ACTIVITYTYPE = 'CHG'
        AND SUBSTRING(DEP.V4_DPTNAME,1,5) IN ('PRIMA','WOMEN','URGIC')
        AND (DATEDIFF(DAY,CP.DNCP_POSTDATE,GETDATE())) < 730
    GROUP BY CP.DNCP_PATIENTID
    ) AS MAXSVCDATE
    ON (CP.DNCP_PATIENTID = MAXSVCDATE.PSNNMBR AND CP.DNCP_FROMSERVICEDATE = MAXSVCDATE.SVCDT AND CP.DNCP_AMOUNT_CHARGE = MAXSVCDATE.CHGAMT)
WHERE CP.OFFICE_ID = 'EDQV'
```

The intended result would be the top record in the picture above with the charge of 217.  Thank you so much for any help you can provide.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have to group not only by patient no on your subquery, but also by DNCP_FROMSERVICEDATE so the only max you would have is the DNCP_AMOUNT_CHARGE so you get a list of patients by day and the max charge for THAT day, then you have to filter that somehow because you're gonna get multiples per patient, maybe more groupings on the main query or a date filter or just MAX(DNCP_AMOUNT_CHARGE) on the main query and that's the only column you pull from the subquery.

hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Yes, I thought about grouping that way in the inner join query but, as you stated, I would return 4 lines for the above example, which would repeat the patient info 4 times in my results.  I'm trying to find the best way to prevent that.  I could do a second inner join subquery inside the first to limit twice before hitting the main query. Is that the best option or is there a simpler, cleaner method that I'm not thinking of?  Thanks!